# problem with update 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

i have 12.04 LTS but i have a strange problem from a while

every time i try to do an update an error window apears with "check your internet connection"

and i have tried to update file by file which was boring and very not exciting

finally I found 4 files those was the problem

libproxy1 (size: 57kB)
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings (size : 22kB)
libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager (size :7kB)
python-libproxy (size:5kB)

by the way i tries to change the server and this problem still the same
please give a way to end this problem
because every time i need to update i have to look for those files and excludes them from the update .... try to look for them into 170 files (I did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to do it from console with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If the later command fails, comment here with the a link to the full output on [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) please.

Comment: Actually the same problem happened again with the 14.04 and the 15.10 and i found out that the problem from the internet provider which forbid any file or words have "proxy" in it ..

Comment: What? Seriously? Please, expose this faulty so-called *provider* so others will know.